# MySQLi prepared statement it is possible to execute a query multiple times

Tags: php, mysqli

I was wondering if it possible to use multiple query this way? that will make my work easy or any other way to do this? just moved on to `mysqli prepared statement` so no idea. thanks you

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'demo');  
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    //do something with row
}

$stmt->bind_param('i', $id2);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    //do something with row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $stmt->get_result()
```

returns mysqli_result and it isn't prepared statement anymore, and as such you cannot do multiple queries.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use "multiple query" with prepared statements. However, you can execute the same query with different set of parameters - that's exactly what prepared statements are for. Judging by your code, you need the second option (so I corrected the question title). All you need is *to supply another value for the already bound variable.*

here you go:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'demo');  
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    //do something with row
}

$id = $id2; // you need to use the same variable you bound
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    //do something with row
}
```

oh and yes, there was also a silly typo in your code, now fixed. You shouldn't overwrite the statement variable.

Comment: Thank you for answering my other question and now i moved to mysqli `prepared statements` i am familar with mysqli so not yet moving to pdo. can you give me example how it will be use or my way is correct?

Comment: I am getting this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::bind_param() `

Comment: @WayToGo have a look at this link. It will help you. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: This example not working who `down-vote` it please explain or correct it please.

Comment: It still have an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::execute() `

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` it seems we are doing something wrong i tried again your code. there is also typo `$id = $id2` =>`$id = $id2;`